# Routes do Slim Framework PHP

Tags: php, rest, slim

Olá pessoal estou com problema ao utilizar a framework Slim... quando tento acessar via get a raiz "/" eu consigo normal, mas quando tento acessar outros metodos como "/hello" ele simplesmente n vai, da erro 
" Not Found

The requested URL /slim/clientes was not found on this server."
nem mesmo com a demo esse erro persiste
segue meu codigo ...

```
    <?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');


$app->get('/', function () {
echo "SlimProdutos";
});

$app->get('/hello', function (){
    echo "Ola";
});


$app->run();

?>
```

segue o .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /var/www/slim

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deixe seu [`htaccess` similar ao do Slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/.htaccess), e coloque no RewriteBase o nome da pasta que você colocou-o `RewriteBase /slim/`. Me avise do resultado.

Comment: Guilherme conseguiu resolver?? Também estou com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia.

Não tenho muita experiência com o Slim, mas a forma que já fiz e funcionou foi assim:

```
$app->get('/hello', function() use ($app) {
 ...
}
```

Meu .htaccess, ficou assim:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado!